# Does Extended Play Mode work on existing save game?

Tags: rage

I am planning to buy the new RAGE extension called The Scorchers. One of the feature implemented is called "Extended Play Mode". Does it work also on an existing save game or I have to start a new game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Extended Play" mode applies to both new games and existing saves. This allows you to play past the game's original ending to further collect achievements and items.

As quoted from the [Steam RAGE: The Scorchers Product Page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209460/):

> Continue exploring the Wasteland long after the final fight with the ‘Extended Play’ option, and relive your favorite missions any time you want with the all-new ‘Combat Scenario Selection’ menu.